# Reverend Spooner's Favorite Movies

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, movies

Reverend Spooner dictated a list of his favorite movies to his befuddled secretary.  That well-meaning lad, unaware of his master's tendency to swap some of the consonants in a phrase, did not realize these were movie titles.  He thought he would improve the sense of the items in the list as you see below.

Your task is to set things right by deducing what Spooner actually said, and identifying the intended movie title.

> 1. Blunder Involving Gliding Toy
> 2. Sunrise Over the Place to Keep Garden Tools
> 3. Purchaser of Easter Flower
> 4. Those Presenting the Bill for Organic Tortillas
> 5. Greetin' the People of Sound Mind by Chimin' a Bell
> 6. A Citrus for a Recordkeeper of Asian Cookware
> 7. Ouchy Milk Farm
> 8. Athlete Whose Home is by the Train Tracks
> 9. Cereal That Will Make You Grow Tall
> 10. Rousing the Warriors

Comment: Some of these would only work if Spooner had pronounced them like a *American* would -- but Spooner, not being American, would not be likely to do so.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Finished!

```
Blunder Involving Gliding Toy
```

> Kite Flub (*Fight Club*)

```
Sunrise Over Place to Keep Garden Tools
```

> Dawn of the Shed (*Shaun of the Dead*)

```
Purchaser of Easter Flower
```

> Lily Buyer (*Billy Liar*)

```
Those Presenting the Bill for Organic Tortillas
```

> Natural Corn Billers (*Natural Born Killers*)

```
Greetin' the People of Sound Mind by Chimin' a Bell
```

> Ringin' in the Sane (*Singin' in the Rain*)

```
Citrus For a Recordkeeper of Asian Cookware
```

> A Wok Clerk Orange (*A Clockwork Orange*)

```
Ouchy Milk Farm
```

> Hurty Dairy (*Dirty Harry*) [Peter Taylor]

```
Athlete Whose Home is by the Train Tracks
```

> Railhouse Jock (*Jailhouse Rock*)

```
Cereal That Will Make You Grow Tall
```

> Height Wheat (*White Heat*)

```
Rousing the Warriors
```

> Waking the Braves (*Breaking the Waves*)

Nice puzzle.

Comment: Wow! Great job so far.  And I was worried I'd made things too obscure.  I've modified #7 slightly.

Comment: Hey! If you're going to nick my answer without attribution then you could at least give me an upvote.

Comment: @petertaylor Sorry. I had genuinely answered this on my own and have just seen your answer, but it's clear that you had arrived at the answer a while before I posted.

Comment: You still haven't got #6.  It's a little more direct than you're thinking.  You were closer before.

Comment: @dennisdeems I'm pretty sure that's it now.

Comment: @GordonK well done!

Comment: This is a great puzzle. I couldn't stop laughing at some of the answers, especially the second and fourth

Comment: Thank you!  I get a good chuckle out of them myself.  :D

Answer (score 7):

#### Ouchy Milk Farm

> Hurty Dairy => Dirty Harry